# ¿Como podria evitar repetir el código en cada condición?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

tengo un codigo JS con una serie de condiciones que se repiten, lamentable y debido a mi poco conocimiento fue la manera que encontré como hacerlo, la verdad funciona, sin embargo me pregunto si existe una manera de hacerlo de tal manera que no tenga que estar repitiendo lo mismo en cada una de ellas. si ven el código notaran que todo es lo mismo excepto por la linea que dice  `Calculo = carroB <` la cual cambia las cantidades agradezco la ayuda.

```
var txteXpress = "";
var txtPayable = "";
var Calculo = "";
var tipoExpress = "";
var infoExpress = "";
var MontoFinal = "";
var colones = "";
if (document.getElementById('Exp-1').checked) {
    txteXpress = "Monto Express";
    txtPayable = "Total IVI";
    Calculo = carroB < 30000 ? 1000 : 0;
    tipoExpress = "Express 1";
    infoExpress = innerHTML = elExpress;
    MontoFinal = ((carroB + Calculo - Cupon) * perC).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    var colones = "¢ ";


} else if (document.getElementById('Exp-2').checked) {
    txteXpress = "Monto Express";
    txtPayable = "Total IVI";
    Calculo = carroB < 30000 ? 1500 : 0;
    tipoExpress = "Express 2";
    infoExpress = innerHTML = elExpress;
    MontoFinal = ((carroB + Calculo - Cupon) * perC).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    var colones = "¢ ";

} else if (document.getElementById('Exp-3').checked) {
    txteXpress = "Monto Express";
    txtPayable = "Total IVI";
    Calculo = carroB < 30000 ? 2000 : 0;
    tipoExpress = "Express 3";
    infoExpress = innerHTML = elExpress;
    MontoFinal = ((carroB + Calculo - Cupon) * perC).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    var colones = "¢ ";

} else if (document.getElementById('wopic').checked) {
    txteXpress = "";
    txtPayable = "Total IVI";
    Calculo = "";
    tipoExpress = "Express 3";
    infoExpress = innerHTML = elExpress;
    MontoFinal = ((carroB + Calculo - Cupon) * perC).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    var colones = "¢ ";
}
```

Comment: Pues poniéndolo al principio, antes del primer `if` o al final después del último, depende de lo que necesites hacer

Comment: Tal como comenta @Benito-B, todo lo que se repite lo puedes colocar fuera del condicional, y dentro sólo lo que no se repite.

Comment: Lo correcto es crear una función para el código que se repite y pasar el número que cambia como parámetro de la misma.

Comment: Lo siento , ya coloque las variables, si el usuario no da check todas son igual a nada. ```var txteXpress = "";
var txtPayable = "";
var Calculo = "";
var tipoExpress = "";
var infoExpress = "";
var MontoFinal = "";
var colones = "";  ```

Answer (score -1):

Crea una función que contenga el código que se repite:

```
if (document.getElementById('Exp-1').checked) {
   Calculo = carroB < 30000 ? 1000 : 0;
   operations()
   tipoExpress = "Express 1";
}
if (document.getElementById('Exp-2').checked) {
   Calculo = carroB < 30000 ? 1500 : 0;
   operations()
   tipoExpress = "Express 2";
}

function operations() {
   txteXpress = "Monto Express";
   txtPayable = "Total IVI";
   infoExpress = innerHTML = elExpress;
   MontoFinal = ((carroB + Calculo - Cupon) * perC).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
   var colones = "¢ ";
}
```

Comment: Considera explicar cómo tú código puede ayudar

Comment: Exelente, Muchas Gracias, hice un pequeño cambio de ```function operations(Calculo)``` a ```function operations()``` y coloque ```operations();```

Comment: de nada @AngeloAguilar sin embargo me he ganado votos negativos :')